# nodejs undefined asynchronous

Tags: node.js, undefined

```
        console.log("validate");

        var team = getItem(place, function(err,data){
          if(err){
             console.log("getItem err");
             console.log(err);
          } else {
              console.log("getItem ok");
              console.log("teamnaam is:" + data);

              return data;
          }
        });

    console.log("test" + team);
    return buildValidationResult(false, 'place', 'This team is' + team);
```

I receive a value of undefined for team. How can I get the data out of getItem.

These is the order of console.log in the log file. 
validate
testundefined
getItem ok
teamnaam is:Ramon the best

So seems like these two lines are kicked off to soon:
console.log("test" + team);
return buildValidationResult(false, 'place', 'This team is' + team);

Who can help me?

Comment: Nodejs is asynchronous so you need to use promise here

Comment: What does `getItem()` do?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function name(cb) {
    getItem(place, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("getItem err");
            cb(err);
        } else {
            console.log("getItem ok");
            console.log("teamnaam is:" + data);
            cb(null, buildValidationResult(false, 'place', 'This team is' + data));
        }
    });
}

// call

name((err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("getItem err", err);
    } else {
        console.log("data", data);
    }
});
```

Comment: It's a call from another function which expects a return